# What embedded platforms does ROS Support?

Tags: ros, embedded, raspberrypi, pandaboard, beagleboard

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My team has been trying to install ROS on several embedded platforms lately – namely Raspberry Pi and Pandaboard – and support seems to be lacking for these platforms.

Is there an up-to-date list of exactly which $200-or-less embedded platforms (Beagleboard, Pandaboard, Raspberry Pi, etc.) ROS currently supports? Are there any groups that focus on making ROS work on cheaper platforms like these?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52410/what-embedded-platforms-does-ros-support?/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know that there is a list of statuses for all of the embedded systems out there, perhaps it is time to form a wiki page in the same way as the [sensors page](http://ros.org/wiki/Sensors).  Perhaps http://ros.org/wiki/EmbeddedPlatforms ?

I believe that the best place to discuss embedded ROS would be the [Embedded ROS SIG](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ros-sig-embedded).

@tfoote recently sent out a survey of users of ARM-based platforms on the ros-users mailling list recently, you can view full text [here](https://code.ros.org/lurker/attach/4@20130112.211053.6cb80ea0.attach)

Finally, OSRF is hosting a [workshop](http://wiki.osrfoundation.org/ROSforProductsWorkshop) in early February, which may also be of some interest to you.

---

Originally posted by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) with karma: 6414 on 2013-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raptor](https://answers.ros.org/users/3237/raptor/) on 2013-01-17**:
I like the idea of the Embedded Platforms page. It can also provide links to getting started pages and helpful documents to get ROS going on those particular embedded systems. Even a more general platforms page with an embedded section in it, listing all the computer platforms that ROS is running on

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2013-01-17**:
Any idea if there'd be a live feed from the workshop? I'm in Montreal, so it'll be difficult to get down there!

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-01-17**:
I just uploaded a raspi iso with the groovy desktop preinstalled. Unfortunately I did not manage to compile PCL and rviz, the rest should work. Instructions how to compile it from source and the image can be found here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/groovy/Installation/Raspbian/Source

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2013-02-09**:
That's awesome! Thanks kalectro!